# Difference between Contract-level metadata and tokenURI in OpenSea?

Tags: solidity, nft, opensea

What is the Difference between [**Contract-level metadata**](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata) and [**tokenURI**](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards#implementing-token-uri) in OpenSea?

Is the [**Contract-level metadata**](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata) mandatory in OpenSea integration?

Answer (score 1):

`contractURI` gives the metadata about the contract (NFT Collection).

`tokenURI` gives the metadata about a particular token (NFT). `tokenURI` will take in a `tokenId` parameter.

Comment: Is it necessary in using OpenSea?

Comment: Without contractURI Opensea doesn't know the name of your collection, as well as description etc. 
Without tokenURI there will be no image, description, stats associated with your NFT